# Is there a way to distinguish "vegetarian" from "vegan" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

I'd like to know whether there is a way to distinguish vegetarian from vegan in Chinese or is the only word available 素食者？

Comment: Most people in China don’t understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vegetarianism 素食主义
means no animals for meals.

veganism 纯素主义
means no animals for meals or clothes.

However, these words are not popular in China. I don't think Chinese people even understand those **jargons**.

You'd better say 我不吃肉 (I don't eat meat) if you are a vegetarian, and you'd better say 我不吃肉，连衣服也不用动物制品 (I don't eat meat, not even animals for clothes) if you are a vegan.

Comment: But veganism is as much about not having eggs or dairy as it is about not wearing wool or silk.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia distinguishes them like this:

> [维根主义（英语：Veganism）](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%B4%94%E7%B4%A0%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9)

and

> [素食主义（英语：vegetarianism）](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%B4%A0%E9%A3%9F%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9)

维根 here is a transliterated loanword from English.

---

Wikipedia also offers the translation:

> 纯素主义

for veganism.

---

Although these words, may, work in their written forms - you might generally not be understood using these words colloquially, because nobody really talks like this. Better alternatives would be:

- 不吃肉 = vegetarianism
- 不吃动物(产)品 = veganism

Comment: vegetarian = 不吃肉。  vegan = 既不吃肉，也不用肉。

Answer (score 3):

A informal way to say it:
vegetarian: 蛋奶素
vegan: 純素

Answer (score 1):

see online dictionaries, e.g. **linguee**: 
vegan food
**纯素食**
​
veganism, a diet consisting solely of plant products
纯素食主义
​
a vegan
**纯素食者**
**iciba**:vegan n. **严格的素食主义者**；
n. A strict vegetarian;
​confirm: **bkrs**:纯素食vegan
vegan food